# how to save and get custom checkbox value

Tags: android, checkbox

I customized the checkbox in dialog layout, you can see the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/remember_choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_btn_holo_light"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/remember_my_choice" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That gives the checkbox a checkbox_btn_holo_light style. But the problem is checkbox can`t save and persist its isChecked() value.

In order to catch the click event I add the onclick tag in xml, and add `onCheckboxClicked` method according to [official document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html#HandlingEvents). see the `onCheckboxClicked` method below.

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    isRememberChoiceChecked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
}
```

what`s worse is when I run the project, click checkbox, the app got crash. the error in logcat show as follow.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onCheckboxClicked(View) in the activity class com.seafile.seadroid2.AccountDetailActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.CheckBox with id 'remember_choice'
```

I wonder why this could happen since .

- So is it possible to custom checkbox layout on **dialog** layout?
- If it is possible to custom the checkbox (set a custom background)， then how to get its check state?

I am confused a lot about this. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: you have to implement OnCheckedChangeListener().

Comment: thanks for your reply, but that does\`t work

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from your xml

```
       android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
```

and in your code for example onCreate method do

```
       CheckBox chx = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.remember_choice);
```

and then you can do :

```
              chx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // here you have your ischecked value do your job
                        // this will fire every time checbox is clicked
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but `chx.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` can\`t catch the onCheckedChanged event at all. Please notice that I use custom checkbox here, so it does\`t work by common way

Answer (score 0):

Button checkboxbtn;
CheckBox none;

none = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chknone);

checkboxbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if ((none.isChecked() == true)) {
                // String strnone = null;
                strnone = "none";
                Log.e("none", strnone);
            }

    });
```